# How to continue execution of a script when a webpage is not reachable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, urllib

What needs to be done is if 10.10.10.2 is reachable the program should `exit()`, but if 10.10.10.2 is not reachable in 10 seconds, 192.168.100.5 will be opened and the program will continue...

Could someone give a small example as to how that could be done?

```
import urllib.request
import eventlet
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib.request

preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2").getcode()
correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5").getcode()

print(100*"#")

#eventlet.monkey_patch()
#with eventlet.Timeout(10):

if True:
    print("Web page status code:",preflash)
    print("Web page is reachable")
else:
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("Web page is reachable")
url_str = 'http://192.168.100.2/globals.xml'

# open webpage and read values
xml_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url_str).read()

# Parses XML doc to String for Terminal output
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

# Finding the neccassary Set points/ Sollwerte from the xmldoc

# prints the order_number from the xmldoc
order_number = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('order_number')
print("The Order number of the current device is:", order_number[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
print(100*"-")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `urlopen` with the `timeout` argument. This raises an URLError after the given time. You can catch this Error
with a [try ... except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
import urllib

try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash)
    print("Web page is reachable")
except urllib.error.URLError:
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5").getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("Web page is reachable")
```